# Dynamically populate image slider

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, slider

I'm using [Vegas](https://vegas.jaysalvat.com/) jQuery plugin to display slideshows for a website. It works like this:

```
$("#example").vegas({
    slides: [
        { src: "/img/slide1.jpg" },
        { src: "/img/slide2.jpg" },
        { src: "/img/slide3.jpg" },
        { src: "/img/slide4.jpg" }
    ]
});
```

I developed a (really simple) php back-end to add and delete pictures.But I don't know how to handle that with the slideshow initialization.

My first idea was to write a csv file containing the number of pictures after the user adds or deletes one. Then, I can read this file with javascript to create an array and use it in `slides`.

As it doesn't seem to me to be a good solution, would you have any technical advice here? Thanks.

**EDIT :** I finally decided to call AJAX on `$(document).ready`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../admin/get_files.php",
    cache: false,
    datatype: "JSON",
    success: function(result){
        data = $.parseJSON(result);
        alert(data);

        $('#slider').vegas({
            slides: data,
            preload: true,
            overlay: '../img/overlays/06.png',
            transition: 'fade'
        });
    }
});
```

The get_files.php function:

```
$dir = '../img/slider/accueil/';
$a = scandir($dir);
$b = count($a);
$res = array();
for($x = 2; $x < $b; $x++) {
    array_push( $res, "{ src: '../img/slider/accueil/" . $a[$x] . "' }");
}

echo json_encode($res);
```

The alert gives this array: `{ src: '../img/slider/accueil/1.jpg' },{ src: '../img/slider/accueil/2.jpg' },{ src: '../img/slider/accueil/3.jpg' }` but the slider doesn't initialize... Any help?

Comment: from where do you get the list of currently available pictures? Filesystem? Database?

Comment: All the pictures are stored in a webserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I was trying to pass a string but a key/value pair was needed. Correct way to do this is:

get_files.php function:

```
$dir = '../img/slider/accueil/';
$a = scandir($dir);
$b = count($a);
$res = array();
for($x = 2; $x < $b; $x++) {
    array_push( $res, "../img/slider/accueil/" . $a[$x]);
}

echo json_encode($res);
```

And the js function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../admin/get_files.php",
    cache: false,
    datatype: "JSON",
    success: function(result){
        data = $.parseJSON(result);
        var dataSrc = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            dataSrc.push({'src': data[i]});
        }            

        $('#slider').vegas({
            slides: dataSrc,
            preload: true,
            overlay: '../img/overlays/06.png',
            transition: 'fade'
        });
    }
});
```